# I want to replace ALL double spaces with single spaces, including those after a period

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this code:

```
item.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
```

and this is the string

```
"The census request file for completion has been attached.  In addition, the attached Client Checklist "
```

It doesn't work: double space remains after the period, so `".  If"` is unchanged.

I don't understand **WHY**!?

Comment: No they don't: this works perfectly fine. If I put your string into a `String s = ...` and then run your replaceAll as `s = s.replaceAll(...);`, then print that `s`, it looks exactly as you'd expect. So you're _definitely_ going to have to show some proof in the form of a [mcve] here.

Comment: The code in this question works as expected. Please add debugging info, for example the code points of the whitespace characters after the period, to help identify the problem. No problem exists based on information in the question.

Comment: It doesn't work: there is some issue with . in the string, but I don't know what is the problem exactly? Here it is:
https://cdn3.bbcode0.com/uploads/2021/7/30/c0c2410c284df9e7770c27917bcdeca4-full.png

Comment: Whoever closed this, please reopen it! It's important to me.
Here is the proof that double space remains:
https://cdn3.bbcode0.com/uploads/2021/7/30/c0c2410c284df9e7770c27917bcdeca4-full.png

Answer (score 1):

Since `String.replaceAll()` method is not an in-place operation, you should write like this:

```java
item = item.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
```

Comment: It doesn't work:
https://cdn3.bbcode0.com/uploads/2021/7/30/c0c2410c284df9e7770c27917bcdeca4-full.png
Double empty spaces remain after .